# is there a way to remove the + @ ? signs

Tags: html, forms, mailto

I am setting up a new contact form for e-mail, but I get (+ @?) Signs know someone how to fix it? and maybe you know how it becomes more professional?

[example]

```
                    [Here Company Image]
```

Name:

Email:

Phonenumber:

Subject:

Text:

I tried to follow many instructions, but it doesn't solve my problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAW4c.jpg

this is my Contact form

```
<body>

<div class="contact-form">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
  </div>
<p><span class="error"></span></p><form method="post" action="mailto:MeediaDagbestedingTest@Gmail.com"> 
  <div class="form">
          <div class="form-items"> 
      <input name="Naam" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Naam" id="Naam" required>
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-items">
      <input name="Hier u Email" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Email" id="Hier u Email" required>
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-items">
      <input name="Telefoonnummer" type="Phone" class="input" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" id="Telefoonnummer" required>
      <i class="fas fa-mobile"></i>
    <div class="form-items">
      <input name="Onderwerp" type="subject" class="input" placeholder="Onderwerp" id="Onderwerp" required>
      <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-items">
      <textarea name="Message" class="input message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message....."></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div>
                <button type="action"="mailto:MeediaDagbestedingTest@Gmail.com" class="btn" >Verzenden</button><br>
  </div>


  <div class="social-icons">
    <div class="facebook">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="twitter">
      <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="google">
      <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


</body>
```

Thanks for the help already!

Comment: are you getting this in response of submitted form?

Comment: Try adding `enctype="text/plain"` to your form: `<form method="post" action="mailto:MeediaDagbestedingTest@Gmail.com" enctype="text/plain">`

Comment: **Do not** use a `mailto:` URL for a form: [they have many many problems](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) and will **break for many visitors**.

Comment: i get this in response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `enctype="text/plain"` to your form:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:..." enctype="text/plain">
```

That should ensure every form field is on a separate line and it's more readable.

Note that using `mailto:` does not work for everyone, a lot of people use a web mail client instead of a native mail client.

Comment: thank you i know but i am a beginner in code so i get fast confuse about Email Contacts i thought this is the easy way but then i hear it doesnt work for everyone i did watch a lot of guide video's. but stil don't know how to do them.

Comment: @Fernando — Submit to an HTTP(S) URL. Send the email with server-side code. Just like it says in [the link I provided earlier](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html)

Comment: @Quentin i did read it again. now i know how it works thanks again.